# Java unable to connect to URL containint an umlaut

Tags: java, url

I seem to be unable to establish a connection to an URL with Java that contains an umlaut.

This is the url I'm trying to access: [http://hakkon-aetterni.at/images/Mitglieder/Höttur.jpg](http://hakkon-aetterni.at/images/Mitglieder/H%C3%B6ttur.jpg)

This is my Java code:

```
URL newLinkURL = new URL(newLink);

URLConnection uc = newLinkURL.openConnection();

String curFileContentType = uc.getContentType();
```

newLink url is A String containing the URL mentioned above. When trying to connect to this url i get a 500 Error in response.

Answer (score 2):

You should encode part of the URL to something like this: http://hakkon-aetterni.at/images/Mitglieder/H%C3%B6ttur.jpg

URL class doesn't encodes passed parameter itself.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Call me stupid but it just started to work.. I have no clue why.. been working for hours on this issue now... About the URlEncoder, if I remember correctly then he encodes the whole String, which means he will also encode the "/", right? If so is there a convenient way to encode an url without encoding the url specific characters like "/" ?

Comment: @Markus only feasible solution for me is to reconstruct url with properly encoded path parts